# How to implement an app expires when I send a remote signal?

Tags: android, demo

I need to implement a very specific demo mechanism. It must not expire after some date, or after X days of usage or after X start ups.

I need this app to expire via a remote signal sent by myself!

How do you suggest I implement this? A remote XML file with a special Integer flag or there is a better method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've asked a relatively general question, so the best I can do is give you a general question. If I were you, what I'd do is have your app poll a remote server everytime it starts up. With that poll it provides some sort of unique identifier. When the server get's the response, it looks up the unique identifier to see if that particular instance of the app has expired. If it has, it simple sends a response back saying "yep you're expired". Otherwise it says, "nope, you're still good to go."

Comment: So this is a remote XML or txt file with some value in it? Like 0 for expire and 1 for not expire?

Comment: And yes, it had to be a general question as I could not be more specific :)

Comment: I would tweak this approach little bit and keep the expired tag in app local database. You can reduce network call each time.

Comment: @sandalone It doesn't have to be XML. It can just be a simple string response. 0 or 1 also works.

Comment: @thinksteep How do you mean "local database"? How can I then send a remote signal to finish the demo mode? The app must connect to the net at least once a day, right?!

Comment: @sandalone: No. after first time you get expire token from internet save it to sqllite database. Next time onwards when app opens instead of internet you will check in local database.

Comment: @thinksteep Oh, that. Of course you will do that instead of useless checking the net for the rest of app's life :).